# Errors when installing discord.js

Tags: npm, installation

I've been having some trouble with installing discord.js to my node_modules using windows powershell. I have checked multiple times and know I have the correct version of node, but every time I run npm install discord.js, it will go for awhile then gives me a bunch of errors like so

```
PS C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\Bot> npm install discord.js
```

(I removed the warnings and just left the errors that cause the installation not to work)

> npm ERR! path C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\async-limiter
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! syscall rename npm
>   ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   'C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\async-limiter' ->
>   'C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\Bot\node_modules.async-limiter.DELETE' npm
>   ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm
>   ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-03-26T14_38_26_242Z-debug.log
>   (sorry if this didn't help)

I don't know what is wrong and can't seem to find anything online to help so hoping this might work, Thanks a lot.
(I also have node version 8.10.0)

Comment: Please paste the errors, not screenshot them.

Answer (score 0):

Found this: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17444. There seem to be multiple workarounds there:

> After `npm` got to the point that it was unusable, just before
>   reinstalling it, I had an idea: I opened task manager (I'm using
>   Windows) and found a bunch of instances of nodejs running. I was able
>   to shut them all down. Then when I ran `npm install` again, which at
>   this time was failing 100% of the time, and found that it was able to
>   execute without any problem.

Here is another one:

> Workaround: Our standard workaround for this and all other NPM 5.x
>   problems is:
>
> Delete package-lock.json and run NPM again.

Also a few users said it was caused by Malwarebytes Ransomware Protection, try disabling it and check if it fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what I had to do was open powershell on my desktop (not in a folder) and install npm to system32 (default location) then move the files to the folder I wanted them in. To get there, Navigate to the Windows System32 folder. Click the "Start" button and select "Computer." In the left-side window pane, locate and click on "Computer." Locate and click on the "(C:)" drive, locate and click on the "Windows" folder, locate and click on the "System32" folder. There will be a node_modules folder. Feel free to move or copy it, I recommend copying as its annoying to redo the instillation every time you want to add a file to it. `(as in nmp i discord.js or npm i sql)` Hope this works for you! :3 (feel free to message me if it didnt help for a more detailed answer, or walk through lol VampyMaria#4980 `im also still learning node.js and discord.js so I cant really help with coding`)